# Nested Vector Iterator - Displaying n'th Vector Only

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

Please bear with me if the answer to this is blindingly obvious, I'm pretty new to the STL.

So what I have is a nested vector. The iterator works as expected, displaying the values stored in each vector in the nested vector sequentially.

My question is, would there be any way to only output the values held in the n'th vector? Given below is the iterator code.

(I'm not using `auto` as I'm using an older version of C++).

```
vector<vector<double> >::iterator row;
vector<double>::iterator  col;
for (row = attrVectors.begin(); row != attrVectors.end(); ++row)
    for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); ++col) {
         //I presume I would somehow need to edit this part.
         cout<<" "<< *col;
    }
```

I hope the question is clear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about adding a counter and checking a modulo division?

Comment: How would I do that? Thanks for the edit by the way.

Comment: The outer vector `attrVectors` is a vector of vectors. What I'd like to display are the contents of each vector held - individually. I hope that's clear!

Comment: Then you just address the inner vector using `n` as index for the outer vector: `outer_vector[n]`.

Comment: @CollinOladimeji So the content of each vector, or only the n'th vector?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ as given in a previous solution - `cout<<" "<<(*row)[n];`?

Comment: @GáborAngyal the content of each vector, but not all at once - one at a time.

Comment: _@CollinOladimeji_ No, what's pointed out in @GáborAngyal's answer.

Comment: @CollinOladimeji Then I think you have your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, it is really simple:

```
void pintNthVector(const vector<vector<double> > &attrVectors, int n)
{
  vector<double>::iterator  col;
  vector<double> &row = attrVectors[n];
  for (col = row.begin(); col != row.end(); ++col) {
     cout<<" "<< *col;
  }
}
```

Comment: this gives the n'th row, not the n'th column, I think.

Comment: @davidhigh "values held in the n'th vector" Maybe I'm wrong, but I do not see anyithing in the question that would suggest he needs the n th column.

Comment: Angyal: you're right, after reading it again it seems that this is the correct answer.

Comment: @GáborAngyal I'd rather use a reference for `row`: `vector<double>& row = attrVectors[n];` instead of the copy.

Comment: Also `const`'ness woul be a good idea, when just printing, and a reference parameter would save another copy.